# Cost of merging two hashmaps

Tags: java, performance, asymptotic-complexity

Let's say I have two HashMaps as follow

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
HashMap<Character, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

Now I want to merge these two together and put them into another HashMap as map3

what would be the best way to do this in terms of asymptotic complexity.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance you can use an `int[]` provided you can make assumptions about the range of letters you want to count.  This has the same time complexity but is many times faster.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of asymptotic complexity it means creating a new map and adding all elements of each map to it. So T(insertion) * (m + n) (I won't reveal the answer in case this is homework!). A java hash map is no more efficient than a text book hash map, so there are no shortcuts there. Finally, if you can arbitrarily modify either one of the two maps, I would recommend merging the smaller into the larger. That will save the time spent iterating through the large map and might save some time spent in memory allocation.

Comment: Here is a source for your further consideration [http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/HashMap.java.htm](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/HashMap.java.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do what you want is:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> map3 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
map3.putAll(map1);
map3.putAll(map2);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: One could also use the copy constructor ```HashMap<Character, Integer> map3 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(map1);``` then ```map3.putAll(map2)```